# Calculation of propensity score using cox regression analysis

Tags: survival, cox-model, propensity-scores

I want to assess the association of a treatment with survival time in patients.
The background information of patients like age and severity differ between the treatment group and non-treatment group.
So I want to do propensity score matching to pick up patients with the treatment and background-matched patients without the treatment. After the matching, I want to assess the association using cox regressoin analysis in the matched data.

The treatment is a time-dependent covariate. Thus, the start of follow-up is not same as the treatment time.
The background information of patients are not time-dependent covariates. The information was obtained at the start of follow-up.

In general, the propensity score was calculated by the logistic regression analysis. (dependent variable: treatment or non-treatment, independent variables: background information)
In this case, is it possible to calculated the propensity score by the cos regression analysis? (dependent variable: tmee-to event data (event = treatment), independent variables: background information)

Could you give me any advice?

Comment: Have you looked into structural equation models? I believe they would be appropriate for this type of situation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Thank you for your comment. I don't known about it very well. Can the time-to-event data be applied to the model?

Comment: I could perform the calculation by using the marginal structural model!